# Beamer: how to avoid image being shifted due to length of text underneath?

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, positioning

**I have the following code:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{2014}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{smallcat.jpg}
    \caption{Smallcat}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

Sunny, yesterday my life was filled with rain
Sunny, you smiled at me and really eased the pain
The dark days are gone, and the bright days are here
My Sunny one shines so sincere
Sunny one so true, I love you

Sunny, thank you for the sunshine bouquet
Sunny, thank you for the love you brought my way
You gave to me your all and all
Now I feel ten feet tall
Sunny one so true, I love you

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{smallcat.jpg}
    \caption{Smallcat}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
Sunny, thank you for the truth you let me see

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Which generates the following two slides:**

[image]

[image]

**Observe that the image of the cat has been shifted downward in the second slide due to the length of text.**

**How do I ensure that the image of the cat remains in the position of the first slide?**

Comment: `\begin{frame}[t]` everywhere

Comment: @HenriMenke Oh, so simple. I thought you needed to use overlay or something like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be a bit against the overlays, but I would strongly suggest it
considering the control you achieve. Moreover, future adjustments become
a breeze. Leaving aside others, just think of a simple scenario, you have placed the same image at the top of ten slides, and now you want to adjust the size a bit. Is not overlay a better solution?

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{2014}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{smallcat.jpg}
    \caption{Smallcat}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{overprint}
  \onslide<+>

  Sunny, yesterday my life was filled with rain Sunny, you smiled at
  me and really eased the pain The dark days are gone, and the bright
  days are here My Sunny one shines so sincere Sunny one so true, I
  love you

  Sunny, thank you for the sunshine bouquet Sunny, thank you for the
  love you brought my way You gave to me your all and all Now I feel
  ten feet tall Sunny one so true, I love you

  \onslide<+>

  Sunny, thank you for the truth you let me see
\end{overprint}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

The part before `\begin{overprint}` is the static part. In your
case, it is the figure. The part between `\begin{overprint}`
and `\end{overprint}` is the dynamic or overlay part.
Each `\onslide` starts a different display.

To learn more about this wonderful feature of this dynamism, please
see Section **9.5
Dynamically Changing Text or Images** of [beamer documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

---

[image]

Comment: Hi, Masroor, what if to display figures of a similar size, but not necessarily the same figure? i.e., not the same cat picture?

Comment: @DetectiveMooch That is also definitely doable. The options range from going for completely different slides (exhaustive option) with manual adjustment of sizes, to using `\onslide<1-2> first cat picture`, `\onslide<3-4> second cat picture` in the top `overprint` and  put matching texts in a bottom `overprint`. If you need more assistance, please post a different question clearly specifying your needs. And we can answer quickly when we have at least some codes which can be compiled readily, even if not with expected results.

Comment: Hi, how did you make the animation? And no sorry I tried using overlay for multiple images but it couldn't work. I will post a question.

Comment: @DetectiveMooch Made the animation:  `convert slide.pdf slide.gif` in Ubuntu. You may need to adjust the speed.

Comment: @DetectiveMooch Yes, do please post a question with your code. Will try to assist to the best of my ability.