# Beamer: how to avoid image being shifted due to length of text underneath for two images of the same size?

Tags: beamer, align, overlays

This is a follow up to a previous question of mine: [Beamer: how to avoid image being shifted due to length of text underneath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388936/beamer-how-to-avoid-image-being-shifted-due-to-length-of-text-underneath)

I have the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{2014}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{cat1.jpg}
    \caption{Cat Lying on a Sofa}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

Sunny, yesterday my life was filled with rain
Sunny, you smiled at me and really eased the pain
The dark days are gone, and the bright days are here
My Sunny one shines so sincere
Sunny one so true, I love you

Sunny, thank you for the sunshine bouquet
Sunny, thank you for the love you brought my way
You gave to me your all and all
Now I feel ten feet tall
Sunny one so true, I love you

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title} 
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{cat2.jpg}
    \caption{Cat Sitting Inside of a Box}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

Sunny, thank you for the truth you let me see

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which generates:

[image]

followed by

[image]

Both of these images are 480 X 360. However, due to the amount of text underneath, the location of the images are shifted (different amount of white space from the top of the page).

Is it possible to use overlay and some other method so that the two images are aligned at the position of the image of the cat of the first slide?

---

cat images:

1. https://www.librarycat.com/boomer-cat-jejune/
2. https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gCrxcjWjNA4/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: While your cats are cute, we are not able to compile your code as we don't have these images. Please have a look at the images included in the `mwe` package, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/36296

Comment: the comment to your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388936/beamer-how-to-avoid-image-being-shifted-due-to-length-of-text-underneath#comment964905_388936 works as well for this example

Comment: The down voters, you need to tell him what is wrong with this question. I don't see any lack of investigation from this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389101/14103) is perfectly suited for your scenario under consideration. Please use it, by all means, if the situation does not change. There is no need to make life more complicated than is required.

I will put forth here another set of slides just to demonstrate where both image and text overlays are needed. Please pay special attention to the slide numbers inside the overlays.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample Title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{2014}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sample Frame Title}

  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1-2,4>
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{cat1.jpg}
      \caption{Cat Lying on a Sofa}
      \label{fig:my_label1}
    \end{figure}
    \onslide<3,5>
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{cat2.jpg}
      \caption{Cat Sitting Inside of a Box}
      \label{fig:my_label2}
    \end{figure}
  \end{overprint}


  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1>
    Sunny, yesterday my life was filled with rain
    Sunny, you smiled at me and really eased the pain
    The dark days are gone, and the bright days are here
    My Sunny one shines so sincere
    Sunny one so true, I love you

    Sunny, thank you for the sunshine bouquet
    Sunny, thank you for the love you brought my way
    You gave to me your all and all
    Now I feel ten feet tall
    Sunny one so true, I love you

    \onslide<2-3>
    Sunny, I can tell you this in many ways

    \onslide<4-5>
    Sunny, thank you for the truths you let me see
  \end{overprint}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Same answer as to your previous question:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388936/beamer-how-to-avoid-image-being-shifted-due-to-length-of-text-underneath#comment964905_388936) top aligned frames will spare you much hassle with alignment:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}
    \caption{Cat Lying on a Sofa}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

Sunny, yesterday my life was filled with rain
Sunny, you smiled at me and really eased the pain
The dark days are gone, and the bright days are here
My Sunny one shines so sincere
Sunny one so true, I love you

Sunny, thank you for the sunshine bouquet
Sunny, thank you for the love you brought my way
You gave to me your all and all
Now I feel ten feet tall
Sunny one so true, I love you

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title} 
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}
    \caption{Cat Sitting Inside of a Box}
    \label{fig:my_label_a}
\end{figure}

Sunny, thank you for the truth you let me see

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*(as both text and images are changing, I don't see why this should be an overlay)*